# jquery popup div on click an element in a form

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

i have a form with four elements. i need to open a jquery popup when click on image that i set as fourth element in my form. popup window contains another form and a submit button. herepopup not coming. what wil i do.

this is my form

```
echo "<div class=\"addform\">
                                    <form method='GET'  action=\"update_events.php\">\n";
            echo "  <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"column1\" value=\"".$row['event_id']."\"/>\n";
            echo "  <input type=\"text\" name=\"column2\" value=\"".$row['event_name']."\"/>\n";
            echo "  <input type=\"text\" name=\"column3\" value=\"".$row['description']."\"/>\n";
            echo "  <input type=\"image\" src=\"images/update.png\"  id=\"update_event\" alt=\"Update Row\" class=\"topopup\" onClick=\"callPopup(".$row['event_id'].")\";  title=\"Update Row\">\n";

        }
                        echo "</table></form><br />\n";
```

this is my jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                function callPopup(id) {
                    console.log(id);

                    var datastring = "&event_id="+id;

                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'event_edit_popup.php', //enter needed url here
                        data: datastring,
                        type: 'get', //here u can set type as get or post
                        success: function(data) {
                        $('.popupContent').html(data);
                                console.log(data);
            $('.loader1').hide();
            $("#popup_content").after(data);
                            // u can see returned data in console log.
                            // here, after ajax call,u can show popup.
                        }
                    });
                };


            </script>
```

and this is my popup div

```
<div id="toPopup">
            <div class="close"></div>
            <span class="ecs_tooltip">Press Esc to close <span class="arrow"></span></span>
            <div id="popup_content"> <!--your content start-->


            <p align="center">edit company</p>
            </div> <!--your content end-->

            </div> <!--toPopup end-->

            <div class="loader"></div>
            <div id="backgroundPopup"></div>
```

Comment: where click function ?

Comment: @ShibinRagh onClick=\"callPopup(".$row['event_id']."); as the fourth input element of the form.

Comment: Your code is broken. You're never closing the `onclick`.

Comment: thnx @GerbenJacobs . even now also popup div is not coming.

Answer (score 0):

First mistake in your form is not complete and second is there is no input `type='image'` if you want to display image than you use image tag.

Please follow the code I hope it will be helpful to you:

```
<div class='addform'>
    <form method='GET'  action='update_events.php'>
            <input type='hidden' name='column1' value="123"/>
            <input type='text' name='column2' value="456"/>
            <input type='text' name='column3' value="789"/>
        <img src='images/update.png'  id='update_event' alt='Update Row' class='topopup' onClick='callPopup("1")' title='Update Row'/>
    </form>
</div>
```

Now jQuery code:

```
$("#update_event").click(function() { alert('sdf'); });
```

Now instead of alert you can use your ajax call for pop up.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to give the image an id.. say id="clickme"
and in the jquery script:-
$('document').ready(function(){
$('#clickme').click(function(){ $('#topopup').show(220);}); });

Again u can add in transitions in the css of the topopup to give it various effects.

Also to hide the pop up:-

$('document').ready(function(){
$('#backgroundPopup').click(function(){ $('#topopup,#backgroundPopup').hide(220);}); });

//This is assuming that you want the popup to be closed when u click on the background